# Where to perform validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, carrierwave

If I have two models, and am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` where should I be putting my validations for the child model.

For example, if I want to validate the images size and limit (ie only allow the user to upload 3 images) should I be validating in the Animal or AnimalImage model

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animal_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :animal_images, allow_destroy: :true
end


class AnimalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, AnimalImageUploader
  belongs_to :animal
end
```

I am using carrierwave to upload my images. I have noticed they have some built in helper methods but from the examples I have seen the image is always in the parent model (ie a user having an avatar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of images per Animal, you have to add this validation to the Animal model. If you want to validate something on individual images (e.g. file type, size, etc.) then these go to the AnimalImage model.

For example:

```
class Animal
  validate :limit_num_of_images

  def limit_num_of_images
    errors.add(:animal_images, :less_than_or_equal_to, count: 3) if animal_images.size > 3
  end
end
```

This example is very simplistic but it should get you started. One thing missing for example, is any checks about valid images. You might want to only take into account the number of valid images.

Comment: thank you, this validation will take place after the images have been created though wont it? can it be done before ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "created". Usually, the parent and children records are INSERTed inside a transaction that is ROLLBACKed if any validation fails. Then you're left with in-memory objects that are not persisted to the database. Somewhere along this path, Carrierwave saves the files to disk. I don't remember the specific sequence of events and callbacks, but it might be possible that you end up with leftover files on the disk. You should never get any records in the database, though.

Comment: no i don't get anything in the database and i can see the rollback in the console..ahh upon closer inspection it is using a tmp file, and then the user has to delete the images that have taken them over the limit

Comment: Danger here - it will not stop from creating new images with `Image.create(animal: some_animal)` as it will not run parent validations. It will only work when animal is being created, later on `animal.images << new_image` will add new image regardless of a number of images.

Comment: @BroiSatse good point! I think you can avoid that by adding `validates_associated :animal` in the AnimalImage model.

Comment: @Teoulas - It might work, however it might break encapsulation, as it is not Image concern to worry about how many of them they have. Also normally you don't want to run the whole set of parent validations when creating new image. It seems like sth which should be treated with association callback.

Comment: Well actually before_save hook won't do it as well, so probably validating parent on child creation/save is a way to go. Don't like it though. It seems a s pretty common problem, so I'll try to write a gem for this.